# Entity Framework taking minutes to save 7500 entries

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I've got a pair of entity classes called signal and data:

```
public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
    }

    public int DataID { get; set; }

    public double ElapsedTime { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class Signal
{
    public Signal()
    {
        Data = new List<Data>();
    }

    public int SignalID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}
```

During normal operation, I initialize the database context and create the necessary signals (12 of them), then dispose the context.

Later, data is being acquired from hardware and I initialize the context again, create Data objects, and add them to the appropriate Signal. The acquisition starts and stops but over the course of the whole thing we end up with 625 data points per signal (total of 7500 data points) in several short bursts over about 10 seconds in total. I have a separate thread responsible for saving data to the database, and the hope is that it won't lag far behind the acquisition thread. However, after the acquisition is finished, it takes 6-7 minutes for the data to finish being saved.

Below is the code being called for every 100 data objects. We dequeue a dictionary from the acquisition thread. The dictionary matches up signals with the next 100 data objects that need to be added to them. We then grab the matching signals from the database and add the appropriate data.

```
// Dequeue the next set of data to save 
Dictionary<Signal, List<Data>> dataToSave = null;
while (MeasurementDataToSaveQueue.TryDequeue(out dataToSave) == false && MeasurementDataToSaveQueue.Count > 0)
    if (SequenceAborted || SequenceInProgress == false) break;

if (dataToSave != null && dataToSave.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var pair in dataToSave)
    {
        Signal signal = dbContext.Signals.FirstOrDefault(S => S.SignalID == pair.Key.SignalID);
        signal.Data.AddRange(pair.Value);
    }
}
```

The code above takes 10-20ms per call, and keeps up with the acquisition just fine. However, once all 7500 data objects have been added to the appropriate signal, I call `dbContext.SaveChanges()` and that is what takes several minutes. I've tried saving every time this code runs instead, and each individual save is faster, but the total time is still 6-7 minutes. Is there any way to speed this up? It doesn't seem like it should take that long to update 7500 records.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) should speed up performance significantly.

Comment: Great advice. After getting the package and referencing it, I only had to change one line of code. Inserting 7500 items went from 6-7 minutes down to 5 seconds.